# Copying data from List to UserForm VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am wondering if anyone could help me with this. I have written vba code to achieve goal when i  click on "Button1" macro button in my sheet1 to open userform2 with a searchbox(TextBox) one  CommandButton and List in it.

I have divided the Problem into two Parts. *One is working for me* and *the second one is not*.

**Problem 1 working:**
Than in searchBox I will write some Name(characters) to do a search from existing sheet1 by clicking on SearchButton1. If it finds the data against that search(Name) than

**Problem 2 not working:**
I should be able to edit and save all the data stored against that Name in new userform I have created by the name of Userform33 having 15 TextBoxes and 2  commandButtons in it, one button for "Edit and save" and second for "close form".

> Here is my code for userform2 that will show the data in the form of
> List based on input in SearchBox

Code **Problem 1 WORKING FINE**:

```
> Option Explicit
> 
> Private Sub TextBox1_Change() Me.TextBox1 =
> Format(StrConv(Me.TextBox1, vbLowerCase)) 'hier schreibt er nur noch
> klein
> 
> Dim sh As Worksheet Set sh = Worksheets("LEADS DE") Dim i As Long Dim
> x As Long Dim p As Long Me.ListBox1.Clear
> 
> 'For ListBox Header Me.ListBox1.AddItem "#"
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = leads.Cells(1, 6).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = leads.Cells(1, 7).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = leads.Cells(1, 19).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = leads.Cells(1, 4).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = leads.Cells(1, 21).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = leads.Cells(1, 18).Value
> 
> 
> 
> For i = 2 To sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row For x = 1 To
> Len(sh.Cells(i, 2)) p = Me.TextBox1.TextLength
> 
> If LCase(Mid(sh.Cells(i, 6), x, p)) = Me.TextBox1 And Me.TextBox1 <>
> "" Then     'Mid(sh.Cells(i, 3 <-- die 3 zeigt wo gesucht werden soll
> With Me.ListBox1 .AddItem sh.Cells(i, 2) '.List(ListBox1.ListCount -
> 1, 1) = sh.Cells(i, 3) .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = sh.Cells(i,
> 6) .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = sh.Cells(i, 7)
> .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = sh.Cells(i, 19)
> .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = sh.Cells(i, 4)
> .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = sh.Cells(i, 21)
> .List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = sh.Cells(i, 18)
> 
> End With
> 
> 
> End If Next x Next i
> 
> 
> End Sub
> 
> 
> Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() Dim Zeile As Long
> 
> Me.ListBox1.AddItem "#"
> 
> 
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = leads.Cells(1, 6).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = leads.Cells(1, 7).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = leads.Cells(1, 19).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = leads.Cells(1, 4).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = leads.Cells(1, 21).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = leads.Cells(1, 18).Value
> 
> For Zeile = 2 To leads.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
> Me.ListBox1.AddItem leads.Cells(Zeile, 2).Value

> Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = leads.Cells(Zeile, 6).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 2) = leads.Cells(Zeile, 7).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 3) = leads.Cells(Zeile, 19).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 4) = leads.Cells(Zeile, 4).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 5) = leads.Cells(Zeile, 21).Value
> Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 6) = leads.Cells(Zeile, 18).Value

> Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 7) = leads.Cells(Zeile, 18).Row
> Next Zeile

> End Sub
```

Well above code is working fine!!!

Now Code for **Problem 2** **which is Not Working for Me!**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim check_data As Characters
check_data = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("F")
If check_data = UserForm2.TextBox1 Then
UserForm33.TextBox1 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("B")
UserForm33.TextBox5 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("F")
UserForm33.TextBox8 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("I")
UserForm33.TextBox9 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("J")
UserForm33.TextBox6 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("G")
UserForm33.TextBox7 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("H")
UserForm33.TextBox10 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("K")
UserForm33.TextBox11 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("L")
UserForm33.TextBox14 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("D")
UserForm33.TextBox12 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("N")

UserForm33.TextBox15 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("O")
UserForm33.TextBox4 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("M")
UserForm33.TextBox16 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("P")
UserForm33.TextBox17 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("Q")
UserForm33.TextBox18 = Sheets("LEADS DE").Range("R")

UserForm33.Show
End If
End Sub
```

**Main Problem**:

I am stuck in Problem 2 and not able to **show the data that comes from search** in the form of List **into newly created UserForm33** and than " **edit**(update) and save data " on the same userform33.

Any help is very appreciated from Experts.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Add another column to the Listbox and use column 0 to store the row number for the record. You can set column width to 0 to hide. Add a label to the UserForm33 to store the row number on the spreadsheet that is being edited.

UserForm2 code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' Edit
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    With ListBox1
        i = .ListIndex ' selected row
        If i < 1 Then Exit Sub
        r = .List(i, 0) ' source row from sheet
    End With
    Call UserForm33.LoadForm(r)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1 = Format(StrConv(Me.TextBox1, vbLowerCase))  'hier schreibt er nur noch klein
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    Call FillListbox(Me.TextBox1.Text)
 End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call FillListbox("")
    'ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "0" hide
End Sub

Private Sub FillListbox(s As String)

    Dim Zeile As Long, Lastrow As Long, i As Long, c As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ar
    ar = Array("B", "F", "G", "S", "D", "U", "R")
     
    Set ws = Sheets("LEADS DE")
    Lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    With Me.ListBox1
        For Zeile = 1 To Lastrow
            If Zeile = 1 Or s = "" _
               Or LCase(ws.Cells(Zeile, "F")) Like "*" & s & "*" Then
                .AddItem "#"
                i = .ListCount - 1
                .List(i, 0) = Zeile
                For c = 0 To UBound(ar)
                    .List(i, c + 1) = ws.Cells(Zeile, ar(c))
                Next
            End If
        Next
        .List(0, 1) = "#"
    End With

End Sub
```

UserForm33 code

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' Save
    Call SaveForm
End Sub

Sub LoadForm(r As Long)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arBox, arCol, i As Long
    arBox = Split("1,5,8,9,6,7,10,11,14,12,15,4,16,17,18", ",")
    arCol = Split("B,F,I,J,G,H,K,L,D,N,O,M,P,Q,R", ",")
      
    Set ws = Sheets("LEADS DE")
    With Me
        .Label1 = r
        For i = 0 To UBound(arBox)
            .Controls("TextBox" & arBox(i)) = ws.Cells(r, arCol(i))
        Next
        .Show
    End With

End Sub

Sub SaveForm()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arBox, arCol, i As Long, r As Long
    arBox = Split("1,5,8,9,6,7,10,11,14,12,15,4,16,17,18", ",")
    arCol = Split("B,F,I,J,G,H,K,L,D,N,O,M,P,Q,R", ",")
      
    Set ws = Sheets("LEADS DE")
    With Me
        r = .Label1
        For i = 0 To UBound(arBox)
            ws.Cells(r, arCol(i)) = .Controls("TextBox" & arBox(i))
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: 1802 Thank you so much its working fine.

Comment: I want to ask you a question related to the code.

Comment: Thanks! You are always very supportive and much Talented person in here.

Comment: Bit of a guess but try adding to url `my.arrow.com/api/security/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials`. You can delete your comments I have the code

Comment: I guess there is some technical or spelling error. I can't figure.

Comment: I have deleted the code. I am trying to add it in my URL. But can you please elaborate it a little bit OR may I contact you somewhere else. Like fb, discord?

Comment: Think you need to correct `objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"` to `objHTTP.SetRequestHeader "content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: Thank you so much .... my.arrow.com/api/security/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials". It was really helpful to run it.. Again Thank You

Comment: @AlexG If you corrected the content-type header then putting the parameter in the body of the POST request with `objHTTP.Send "grant_type=client_credentials"` should work without adding it to url which is the way parameters are added to GET requests.

Comment: Yeah! Thank You.I already have done. And I would be very thankful to you again  for correcting me. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hello Sir, CDP1802, I am writing a code to send bulk Whatsapp automate Messages with image using VBA in Excel. But it seems to give errors in it. There are few error which are resolved but still soe errors persists. Can you help please?

Comment: Hello sir, any help would be much appreciated. Here is the code

Comment: Sir Actually When i click on the send button on excel the whatsapp app opens in the pc . The texts also gets written but it doesn’t get send

Comment: Thank you sir for your correction, It is working for me. But I'm not still able to figure out is there anyone who can answer my query related to running VBA code on MAC?

Comment: @alexg https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Whatsapp+%5Bvba%5D

Comment: @CDP1820 Sir I have some message for you in Chat. If you are free Please consider it . I need some guidance on it. Thanks